# Pixlelated borders when i save image as GIF with Transparent In Illustrator

Tags: graphics, adobe-illustrator

World Map Images in Adobe Illustrator CS5

I have an image Map in illustrator CS5 which i want to save in GIF so as to reduce its size for web use. But when i save it, the map boundaries are having some white pixels all along the map boundaries of map.

I really dont know why has happened to it, but cant save it in Png-8, png-24 formate due to size constraint.

Any meaningful answer will be highly appreciate and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is your background a non-changable color? Maybe you can save the image with the same color as a background.

The problem is gifs don't support true transparency.

If this doesn't work can you provide the image you are trying to save (gif and png, I don't have AI right now)? Maybe there will be something I can do about the size or clearing the gif's edges.

Answer (score 1):

transparent GIFs don't have an 8-bit alpha channel, like PNG does: a pixel in a GIF is either there, or it's not: if it's there, you can't see through it.  This often means that an edge between transparent and non-transparent areas looks blocky.

There are two ways to deal with this... either use a PNG 24 (and the Illustrator Save for Web feature will help you to make it smaller), or in Illustrator create a background color layer behind your image before you export to GIF.  If this background color layer is the same as the website you put the image on, the edges will blend nicely.